# Weakening the category-theoretic idea of a limit … but not a weak limit

Tags: category-theory, terminology, limits-colimits

In the words of the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limit):

> In category theory a limit of a diagram $F : D \to C$ in a category $C$ is an object $\lim F$ of $C$ equipped with morphisms to the objects $F(d)$ for all $d \in D$, such that everything in sight commutes. Moreover, the limit $\lim F$ is the *universal* object with this property, i.e. the “most optimized solution” to the problem of finding such an object.

One obvious way to weaken this is the notion of a [weak limit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit):

> A weak limit for a diagram in a category is a cone over that diagram which satisfies the existence property of a limit but not necessarily the uniqueness.

I have encountered a situation where I have the weakening in the opposite direction:  I have uniqueness, but not existence.  That is, instead of guaranteeing at *least* one map making a diagram commute, I guarantee at *most* one.  Does this concept, weaker than a limit but not a weak limit, have a name?

Comment: In the special case of a terminal object, this is called a "subterminal object".  It would be reasonable to generalize this to "sublimits", but I don't think I've ever actually seen that term used.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I like 'sublimit'!  Thanks!

Comment: @ArnaudD., yes, it does, thanks!  In fact [your answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050612) is the same as @‍EricWofsey's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158235/weakening-the-category-theoretic-idea-of-a-limit-but-not-a-weak-limit#comment8611267_4158235), which is a good sign for the acceptability of this term.  I never know what to do in this situation.  Is there a way for me unilaterally to close my question, or do I just vote to close and leave it at that?

Comment: @LSpice I think there is a way, but I don't know how it works. I think if you vote to close it will immediately close the question.

Comment: It turns out that my close vote isn't enough, but there was a little prompt at the top asking me if my question was indeed a duplicate.  When I confirmed that it was, the question was immediately closed.